# VSCode で Python スクリプトを実行すると SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe3'

Tags: python, python3, vscode

タイトルの通りです。言語はPython3です。IDLEで作って動いてたコードを、VS codeで実行すると

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe3' in file /Users/TAKA/Downloads/SpaceTAKA/ランダム俳句.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

と表示されます。これはどういうことでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 実際のコードを提示してもらわないと回答は難しい気がします。質問にあたってはヘルプの [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) も参考にしてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージの指摘は、
「/Users/TAKA/Downloads/SpaceTAKA/ランダム俳句.pyというファイルにASCIIではない文字[（unicodeなどの多バイト文字コードの文字(漢字、ひらかな等))]が含まれている。
それなのに、["# coding: UTF-8"というような]使用文字コードの宣言が為されていない。」という事です。
([]内は、私が補足した部分)

/Users/TAKA/Downloads/SpaceTAKA/ランダム俳句.pyの先頭に、"# coding: UTF-8"という行を追加したら解決するのではないかと思われます。

Comment: エンコーディング宣言が見つからなければ、デフォルトのエンコーディングは UTF-8 です。https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations

Comment: ありがとうございます。# coding: UTF-8　を先頭につけて走らせてみましたが、同様のエラーメッセージが出ました。ちなみに、日本語を一切含んでいない、print("hello") だけのファイルにも同じエラーが出ます

Comment: @SpaceTAKA さん「日本語を一切含んでいない」ように見えて全角空白が存在するのでは？ [空白変換機能](http://itdoc.hitachi.co.jp/manuals/3000/3000635140/U3510205.HTM) UTF-8の全角空白が0xE3,0x80,0x80ですよ。

Comment: 確認してみましたがやはり、print("hello")だけでも動きません